# Chat relative times are being displayed erroneously

Tags: bug, chat, design

What happened:

- Chatting in chat on 2015-12-31 afternoon.
- Close laptop (standby).
- Resume from standby at 2016-01-01 afternoon.
- Encounter the following behavior:

[image: excessive relative times being displayed]

Not every single time interval should be displayed here. (Why are there even words/templates for shorter time periods than an hour?)

Apparently this is caused by reconnecting within a certain timespan. See Doorknob's answer for how to repro.

Comment: Ummm... You do realize that today is January 21st? That's a few weeks after...

Comment: @Zizouz212 So, how does that affect this issue?

Comment: I'm making note that it took you twenty days before you came out here and reported it. I didn't say anything about the issue...

Comment: @Zizouz212 And that has nothing to do with the issue. I documented it when I encountered it and what ever my reason was that this post was delayed (whether personal or not) are completely irrelevant to this discussion, and so is your comment. It just reads as an accusation to be honest.

Comment: This bug is unrelated to the new year. It is caused when you are reconnected to the same WebSocket connection after being disconnected; I've experienced this bug myself before (on not-New-Year's-Day, of course). Not sure why you're getting downvotes, though.

Comment: @Doorknob Thanks for the explanation. If you want to add that as an answer I can mark it accepted (I'd prefer that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug is unrelated to the new year. It is caused when

- You are disconnected from the internet (or from the chat server) while the chat tab is still open.
- You reconnected within (x) amount of time (I'm not sure how long is too long).
- Upon reconnecting, you are connected to the same WebSocket session.

I've experienced this bug myself before, on days other than New Year's. I'm not sure why it happens, but I'm fairly certain that this is how it can be reproduced.